# How to know which button is first clicked within 10 buttons an

Tags: java, android

I am creating a game in android where there will be 10 shuffled numbers which user have to memorize and then click fro 1-10 one by one.
I want to know is there any function or way in android to know which button is first clicked,then i can set that way the values..thankyou.
I was trying to make a function that will count the number of button clicked then increase its value to match with my buttons:

CODE::

```
 public void settingFirstPressedButton (int buttonPressed)
        {
        if (firstPressedButton == -1)   //when firstPressedButton = -1 it means no button was pressed
          firstPressedButton = buttonPressed;
        }



then:

b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(firstPressedButton==-1){
                if(b1.getText()=="1"){
                    b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    break;
                }}

                else {
                    if(firstPressedButton==0){
                        if(b1.getText()=="2"){
                            b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            break;
                        }
                        }


                        else {
                            if(firstPressedButton==1){
                                if(b1.getText()=="3"){
                                    b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                    break;

                                }       }




                    else {
                        if(firstPressedButton==2){
                            if(b1.getText()=="4"){
                                b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                break;
                            }


                        }


                        else {
                            if(firstPressedButton==3){
                                if(b1.getText()=="5"){
                                    b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                        else {
                            if(firstPressedButton==4){
                                if(b1.getText()=="6"){
                                    b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }



                            else {
                                if(firstPressedButton==5){
                                    if(b1.getText()=="6"){
                                        b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            else {
                                if(firstPressedButton==6){
                                    if(b1.getText()=="7"){
                                        b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                        break;
                                    }   
                        }

                                else {
                                    if(firstPressedButton==7){
                                        if(b1.getText()=="8"){
                                            b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                            break;
                                        }


                                        else {
                                            if(firstPressedButton==8){
                                                if(b1.getText()=="9"){
                                                    b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                                    break;
                                                }}

                                            else {
                                                if(firstPressedButton==9){
                                                    if(b1.getText()=="10"){
                                                        b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                                        break;
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 3):

you can use your own `Activity` as `OnClickListener` . For instance

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        f1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.f1);
        f2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.f2);
        :
        :
        f1.setOnClickListener(this);
        f2.setOnClickListener(this);
        :
        :
        :
     }


}
```

you have to implement the onClick method and switch upon view.getId():

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.f1:
         // your click action
        break;
    case R.id.f2:
         // your click action
        break;
            :
            :
    }
}
```

if you want array of buttons then

```
Button btns[]=new Button[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        btns[i] = new Button(this);
        btns[i].setText(""+i);
    }
```

If you want all of them to do the same thing you could use a for loop to loop over the array like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i< btns.length; i++){
    btns[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            //do something
            Log.d("Button click","Value " +  btns[i].getText() ;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In this way i will know which button is clicked ,but actually what i want to know which one is first clicked,so I can equalize the values from 1-10 with the clicked order to make it

Comment: i was trying to make a function that will count the button clicked order :

Comment: is the 10 shuffled numbers were buttons

Comment: I just want to know how to implement when i click the first button it will be having 1 and second will be having 2 and so on....but the button will be on random order..